# making a function not to work for a few some seconds in java

Tags: java, function

I have a login function.I want my function not work for example 10 seconds if 
the user call it for more than 5 time.what should i do for that?I will be glad 
if some one answer my question.

Comment: Keep count, if over 5x, start a timer.

Comment: Show us your current code. Read about [mcve]. Read some stuff at the [help] in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You need to record failed login attempts for a user (e.g. in `database`) and once it reaches the threshold, you need to return error response from `login` method for configurable amount of time from the last failed login attempt, e.g.:

- When a login fails, log it into database (along with timestamp)
- During login attempt, get failed attempt count and check whether it has reached the configured threshold
- If it is over the threshold, check the timestamp for last login and block the call if current date is let's say within `x` minutes from that timestamp
- On successful login, clear all the failed attempts

Answer (score 1):

> function not work for example 10 seconds

You need to be specific on what exactly you mean by **function not to work**. But if you simply wanted to block the method call for `x` seconds, follow the below approach:

You need to create a `counter` to count the number of attempts and then `if(counter>5)` then use [Thread.sleep(10000)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) to make the request to hold (sleep) for 10 seconds. Ideally, the `counter` value should be persisted to a database (or any other storage) and read it again to validate the number of attempts.

But, I strongly suggest you follow @Darshan's answer which makes more sense.

Comment: And how are you going to maintain this `counter` across multiple login requests?

Comment: Added explanation on your query

Comment: Blocking a thread is a poor solution to this problem. Darshan's answer is a  more suitable way to handle failed login attempts

Comment: @Aerus Thanks, I agree with you, I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

First you need to identify the user .

This can be done on the basis of IP .

Have a ConcurrentHashMap

```
   ConcurrentHashMap<String,Long>IpAddressValidationMap  // String is the Ip address and Long is the timeInMilleseconds
```

You make a filter and put a check

```
     public void prefilterFunction(RequestObject object)
      {
          String ip=object.getIP(); // just an example not the standard call for getting Ip addr
           Long time=IpAddressValidationMap.get(ip);
           if(time!=null)
           { 
             if(time<THRESHOLD_TIME)
               {
                 return ;  
                 }     
                 else
                {
                 // We allow the user to proceed
                 }
            }
       }

      public void validateLogin(RequestObject object)
      {
       // if the login fails 
         IpAddressValidationMap.put(ipAddr,System.currentTimeinMIllis());   
       }
```